# Facebook Marketing API App Access Tokens, How do they work?

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, https

I want to make an application that runs in the background on a server, and syncs ad information from Facebook to a database on my server periodically (say once per hour).

The application will have no user interaction at all, meaning there is no user to click "I'm okay with Facebook using my info" every time you need to authenticate.

I found this in their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

The problem is, it doesn't seem to work. I can generate an access_token just fine. Example here:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=123456789012345&client_secret=s3cr3tt0k3n12a4zz1345a6fgx5aa3f6&grant_type=client_credentials'

access_token=123456789012345|SomeRandomLettersAndNumbers
```

However, when I go to use it I just get permission denied errors:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/adaccounts?access_token=123456789012345|SomeRandomLettersAndNumbers'

{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"DQ8ysX2mHCu"}}
```

Same thing happens when I make the request via their explorer tool found here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Notes:

- I have an app set up.
- I am the admin.
- I claimed the app on my business account.
- I created one ad account.
- It is not a Native / Desktop app.
- Important one: *I can get the info if I use a user token instead of an app token, but this requires me to be on a website, and click through a popup window, which obviously I can't do every hour for my server-side app.*

I'm not sure if I have to set the permissions somewhere to allow me to use the access token, or maybe I need to set up a "platform" for my app (none of the available ones seem to fit).

**UPDATE:**

The answer to this question is to use a system user as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/04/05/system-user-rollout/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for updating and posting the link!